# how to split geom to lat long

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table with a Column `GEOM` and data is like below

```
Geom

MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,32638,MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(732321.244349674,2669885.06999747,NULL),NULL,NULL)
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,32638,MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(732561.034224563,2671216.49530935,NULL),NULL,NULL)
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,32638,MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(732420.714474628,2671059.35918443,NULL),NULL,NULL)
```

I want to view the above data as like below

```
LAT_LONG
732321.244349674,2669885.06999747
732561.034224563,2671216.49530935
732420.714474628,2671059.35918443
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the values from geometry.sdo_point.x and y.

```
Select table_alias.geometry_column.sdo_point.x,
       table_alias.geometry_column.sdo_point.y
from your_table as table_alias;
```

Or in the form you asked:

```
 Select table_alias.geometry_column.sdo_point.x||','||
           table_alias.geometry_column.sdo_point.y as lat_long
    from your_table as table_alias;
```